# How to split string and extract only one word in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this string where I need to extract only one word to put into a new columns.

```
HELLO WORLD TEST SHOES1 PROJECT
```

The required string is SHOES, but it has '1' beside it.

How can I extract the SHOES only?

Thank you

Comment: Can you give some context for how we know that `SHOES1` is the target word of the five words in the column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use split with sub string

```
string.split(' ')[3].substring(0,4);
```

[3]: Reperesents index 3 of splitted array which is SHOES1 and then substring by 0 to 4 you will definitely get SHOES.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite vague, but taking an educated guess at what you want, a func like

```
def find_and_trim_the_word(stringy, word):
    for w in stringy.split():
        if w.startswith(word):
            return w.rstrip('0123456789')
    return ''
```

might do the trick.  It splits the input string into separate words. If it finds the word, it trims any trailing digits off and then returns the word.
Note that this would also return SHOES if you passed in "SHO" or "SHOE" for *word*.

Answer (score 0):

First to get the word 'SHOES1' you have to use the 'split' method.
Then you can use 'strip' method to remove any unwanted characters or numbers.

So, the final answer would be:

```
"HELLO WORLD TEST SHOES1 PROJECT".split(" ")[3].strip("1")
```